# How to convert 1D matlab array code into Fortran code and to get the values

Tags: matlab, fortran

I want to convert this Matlab code into Fortran code. I have provided the codes here for both Matlab and Fortran. The parameters are also given here.

Matlab code

```matlab
L_10 = 1.0e-10;
e = 0.4;
n = 100000;
R = 3.1e+5;
K0_10 = 1.0e-10;
Ci  = 1.0e-15;
zv  = 1.2;
Dv  = 1
Rho = 2.0e-4
dt  = 0.01

for i=1:n
     L_10(i+1) = L_10(i) + dt*(e*K0_10- R*L_10(i)*Ci- zv*Dv*L_10(i)*Rho);
end
```

I have written the following Fortran code but it does not work

```
real, dimension (:), allocatable:: L_10
real, parameter :: e = 0.4
integer, parameter :: n  = 100000
real, parameter :: R  = 3.1e+5
real, parameter :: K0_10 = 1.0e-10
real, parameter :: Ci = 1.0e-15
real, parameter :: zv = 1.2
real, parameter :: Dv = 1.0
real, parameter :: Rho  = 2.0e-4
real, parameter :: dt = 0.01
integer:: i

do i=1:n
   L_10(i+1) = L_10(i) + dt*(e*K0_10- R*L_10(i)*Ci- zv*Dv*L_10(i)*Rho);
end
```

How to initialize the array value in the Fortran code? How the iteration will work in Fortran? It works perfectly well in Matlab.

Comment: I am actually more concerned about the generation of an array in Fortran do loop. But you have rightly spotted the syntax error there too.

Answer (score 0):

I can immediately see two problems with the Fortran.  You've chosen to make `L_10` allocatable, but the code doesn't allocate it.  You could either make it static, by changing its declaration to

```
real, dimension (n+1) :: L_10
```

If you choose this approach you'll have to move the declaration until after the declaration of `n` itself, the compiler won't work with forward declarations.  The alternative would be to leave the declaration as it is but to insert the statement

```
allocate(L_10(n+1))
```

after the declarations but before you try to make first use of the array.  Review your documentation for the `allocate` statement and learn how to get a status code reported in case things go awry.

You can then set the value of all elements in the same way you do in Matlab,

```
L_10 = 1.0e-10
```

You have the syntax for the `do` statement wrong, it should start with the line

```
do i = 1, n
```

with a comma where Matlab uses the colon.

There may be other problems in the Fortran which I haven't spotted, but your compiler will help you there.

Comment: ... such as a missing `end do`. And some would say adding `implicit none` is an important aspect of language conversion.

Comment: Gotta leave the compiler some errors to find !  And yes, `implicit none`.

Comment: I've left the error for the compiler to find, but it's probably important to give the correct size of the array (easy for a user to overlook and Fortran is somewhat less forgiving in that regard than Matlab). You know about rollbacks, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This program in Fortran is producing the same output as in Matlab. The iteration of array is different in do loop in Fortran as shown below. The iteration is saved in Fortran without indexing but in Matlab, it is done with indexed as shown in Matlab code.

```
program oneDimention 
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: n  = 10
    real, dimension (n):: L_10
    real, parameter :: e = 0.4
    real, parameter :: R  = 3.1e+5
    real, parameter :: K0_10 = 1.0e-10
    real, parameter :: Ci = 1.0e-15
    real, parameter :: zv = 1.2
    real, parameter :: Dv = 1.0
    real, parameter :: Rho  = 2.0e-4
    real, parameter :: dt = 0.01
    integer:: i

    L_10 = 1.0e-10

    do i=1,n
           L_10 = L_10(i) + dt*(e*K0_10- R*L_10(i)*Ci- zv*Dv*L_10(i)*Rho);
    print*,L_10(i)
    end do

end program oneDimention
```

---

Comment: `L_10=...` and `L_10(i)=...` are very different things.

Comment: Yeah. You are right about it. That's the issue of working with different platforms. It is hard to figure out the syntax at the beginning for new users like me.